# Compute $ 2^{1212} \!\!\mod {2013}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Condition: Using Fermat's Little Theorem,

we get $ 2^{2012} \equiv 1 \!\!\mod {2013}$.

Hence, $2^{1006} \equiv 1 \!\!\mod {2013}$.

But I can't seem to go further than here$\ldots$ Any suggestions?

Comment: Apart from 2013 not being prime, if you look at a prime like 2029 instead, it is not true that $2^{(2028/2)}\equiv 1 \mod 2029$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That only holds if $2013$ is prime.
$2013=3\times11\times61$.
So $2^{60}=1\pmod{3}$ and $\!\!\pmod{11}$ and $\!\!\pmod{61}$
$2^{1200}=(2^{60})^{20}=1\pmod{3\times11\times61}$
$2^{1212}=2^{1200}\times2^{12}=1\times4096\pmod{2013}$

Comment: That's a really nice answer. Thanks a mill !